# Abstracting an onClick function that also does state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to abstract away my onClick function(s) into its own file and then later use it in a component's button(s).

However the function needs to conditionally update the state of the component it is being used in.

```
export let ButtonClickHandlers = {
    refreshDatabase: (url: string) => {
        service.fetchJson<any>(url)
        .then(res => {
            if(res.isSuccessStatusCode){
              //update state
            }
            else{
              //update state
            }
        });
    },
    //more functions to be added later
}
```

In my component I want to do something like this:

```
import {ButtonClickHandlers} from '../ButtonClickHandlers';

<button onClick = {ButtonClickHandlers.refreshDatabase} />
```

How do I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have done it, there might be better ways.I have imported the clickevent and passed the context as paremeter

clickevenhandler.js

```
 const clickEvent = (context) => {
    context.setState({ click: true });
 }

 export default clickEvent;
```

my test component

```
 import clickEvent from './clickhandler';

class TestComp extends React.Component<any, any>{
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          click: false
         }
        }
   renderclicked() {
     if (this.state.click) {
         return (<div>clicked</div>);
       }
       else {
           return (<div></div>);
       }
    }
    render() {
       return (<div>Test
               <button onClick={() => clickEvent(this)}>click</button>
            {this.renderclicked()}
           </div>);
    }
}
```